# What are ways to get an output file from spd-say?

Tags: sound

`spd-say Hello!` outputs voice through the speakers. I want to get the output in the form of an audio file. How can I do that?

I've tried looking at the man pages of `spd-say` but I can't find any parameter that can help out. I've also looked at `speech-dispatcher`'s man pages.

As a side quest, it would be nice to know how to redirect audio output of any program to file even if it doesn't support this.

Comment: PulseAudio should be able to do this for you. [Take a look at the answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322990/programmatically-redirect-audio-output-of-specific-program-to-file) as it seems to be very similar to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Matigo thanks for the hint. I don't understand how the answer works though. I've asked for clarification there. Also, this method seems to be fairly complicated. Is there a simpler way? Also, can `spd-say` do it on its own maybe?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29995846/446106 lists a few speech synthesizers for Linux.

I gave each one a try, and [`flite`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/flite.1.html) and [`espeak`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/espeak.1.html) have an option to output to an audio file.

```
sudo apt install flite

flite -t "Hello world"  -o hello.wav
flite -f  hello.txt     -o hello.wav


sudo apt install espeak

espeak  -w stdin.wav  # read from STDIN

espeak     "Hello world"  -w hello.wav
espeak  -f  hello.txt     -w hello.wav
```

`espeak` uses the same voice as `spd-say` (on my system at least).